# Calling an overloaded subroutine when the 'right' one is dependent on the dynamic type of two of its arguments

Tags: vb.net, overloading, dynamic-typing

I am having difficulty in getting the right subroutine selected out of one which has been overloaded many times, each with two arguments.  Perhaps some form of double dispatch would be appropriate, but I can't see any tidy way of doing that when there are two arguments with two (potentially) different types that need to be checked.

Essentially, the example code I created performs as desired, but it seems to me an extremely poor way of doing it. As the types are determined at compile-time, I cannot simply call the sub I want by passing in the two objects I'm trying to test:

```
test(store(0),store(1))
```

would only call a test subroutine with the signature

```
Sub test(cA As Class1, cB As Class1)
```

as the static type of store(x) will always be Class1.

Is some convoluted form of double dispatch feasible or is there a better solution?

```
Option Strict On
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim store As List(Of Class1) = New List(Of Class1)
        store.Add(New Class2)
        store.Add(New Class3)
        If TypeOf (store(0)) Is Class2 Then
            If TypeOf store(1) Is Class2 Then
                test(CType(store(0), Class2), CType(store(1), Class2))
            ElseIf TypeOf store(1) Is Class3 Then
                test(CType(store(0), Class2), CType(store(1), Class3))
                'and so on...
            End If

        ElseIf TypeOf (store(0)) Is Class3 Then
            'relevant tests of store(1)
        ElseIf TypeOf (store(0)) Is Class4 Then
            'relevant tests of store(1)
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub test(cA As Class2, cB As Class2)
        Console.WriteLine(cA.class2SecondUniqueProperty)
        Console.WriteLine("2 and a 2")
    End Sub
    Sub test(cA As Class2, cB As Class3)
        Console.WriteLine("2 and a 3")
    End Sub
    Sub test(cA As Class2, cB As Class4)
        Console.WriteLine(cB.class4UniqueProperty)
        Console.WriteLine("2 and a 4")
    End Sub
    Sub test(cA As Class3, cB As Class2)
        Console.WriteLine("3 and a 2")
    End Sub
    Sub test(cA As Class3, cB As Class3)
        Console.WriteLine("3 and a 3")
    End Sub
    Sub test(cA As Class3, cB As Class4)
        Console.WriteLine("3 and a 4")
    End Sub
    'and so on, for many (but not all) pairs of classes inherited from Class 1.
    Public Class Class1
    End Class
    Public Class Class2
        Inherits Class1
        Property class2UniqueProperty As String = "only present in Class 2"
        Property class2SecondUniqueProperty As String = "only present in Class 2"
        Sub class2UniqueSub()
            'do something that the other classes derrived from Class1 don't
        End Sub
    End Class
    Public Class Class3
        Inherits Class1
        Property class3UniqueProperty As String = "only present in Class 3"
    End Class
    Public Class Class4
        Inherits Class1
        Property class4UniqueProperty As String = "only present in Class 4"
    End Class
    'will be more than 4 classes
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

An overload method is chosen by the **compiler** ([Overload Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb18a48w.aspx)). You are probably looking for a way to choose a method in runtime. Your method of type matching can be a solution but it would be better to place the type resolution code inside `test` method.

Your code is not good from the object oriented programming point of view. A better way is to define a method in clases and call it.

```
Public MustInherit Class Class1
  Public Property TypeNumber as  integer
  Public MustOverride Sub Test(Ca As Class1)
  Public MustOverride Sub SomeMethod()
End Class
Public Class Class2
  Inherits Class1
  Public Sub New()
       TypeNumber = 2
  End Sub

  Property class2UniqueProperty As String = "only present in Class 2"
  Public Overrides Sub Test(Ca As Class1)
      Ca.SomeMethod()
      Console.Writeln(Me.TypeNumber & " and a " & Ca.TypeNumber)
  End Sub
  Public MustOverride Sub SomeMethod()
      Console.Writeln(class2UniqueProperty)
  End Sub
End Class
```

'... continue with other classes

And call uses now

```
store(0).Test(Store(1))
```

It can be that it is not possible to solve your problem without type matching logic but usually it is better to avoid it. The object oriented pattern is usually better manageable than using module methods.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I fully agree my example code is poor OOP.

As I understand it, your suggestion would not allow me to use any of the methods or access any of the properties in the argument class (as it will be viewed as its static class, Class1), which is a problem. This seems to be a single dispatch solution, which I don't think could work here.

That said, your code has made me realise some kind of double dispatch solution might not be as messy as I first thought.

Comment: I admit that the solution is not always usable but I think you are overlooking **Overriding** - Methods are defined in base class (class1) but the execution code is in derived class (class2) and **has access** to its members. So you can access properties of argument classes if you define an unified interface for them.

Comment: I do have some understanding of the concept of overriding and use that elsewhere in this program. I just reread my comment and I think perhaps I wasn't clear about the reason I don't believe this solution would work here. When I talked about the argument class, I meant the instance of a class which is provided as an argument to the test function in your code. The overridden method you use would allow me to use the methods and functions of the object class, but not the argument class.

(Continued below due to char limit.)

Comment: So, I could type:

`store(0).Test(Store(1))`.

Within the test function, I would be able to use functions/properties belonging to the dynamic (runtime) class of store(0) (which is great) but I would only be able to use the functions/properties of the static (compile-time) class of store(1), as opposed to the functions/properties of its dynamic class, which is what I'd need for this to be a full solution to the problem.